# Do Occident or Oriental homes produce more net income?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

In the current game I'm playing, I'm at a cross-roads on whether to build another Occidental colony or an Oriental one, for money production.  I have enough excess supply that building either one would be easier, but I'd like to know **which type of colony generates more money after maintenance and supply costs per house**?

So if I have a fully surrounded market place, with all the requisite support buildings, which type of population earns more money?

Answer (score 3):

The Oriental ones don't have as many levels to reach, but their initial income should be higher.

Answer (score 1):

Occidental towns have a strongly deminishing tax return depending on city size. Up to about 500 people per class (peasant, citizen...) produce maximum tax.

Orientals produce much less tax, but it does not diminish like it does for occidentals. So large oriental towns are likely better than large occidental ones. While small occidental towns are by far the best tax providers. Also note that dates and milk are much more costly to produce than fish and cider.